# Join parts of lists before and after & character

Tags: python, list, join

I am trying to get a list, check if it contains the '&' character, then join the data before and after that character depending on where it is. The '&' position will not always be the same.

Lets say i have a list

```
_list = ['John', 'Adams', '&', 'George', 'Washington']
```

I want to get the values before and after the ampersand and store them as a string to a variable.

```
name_one = "John Adams"
name_two = "George Washington"
```

Keep in mind this would have to be dynamic in that i need to be able to get all of the data before and after no matter how many indices there are

```
_list = ['John', 'Adams', 'Jr.', '&', 'George', 'Washington']
```

Would return

```
name_one = "John Adams Jr."
name_two = "George Washington"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
l = ['John', 'Adams', '&', 'George', 'Washington']
ind = l.index('&')
name_one = ' '.join(l[:ind])
name_two = ' '.join(l[ind+1:])
```

Needless to say, you should be careful about the list not containing the '&' character or containing multiple instances of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list.index` to find the index of the first occurence of`'&'` and then slice before and after that index.

```
def get_names(lst):
    try:
        index = lst.index('&')

    except ValueError:
        ... # return some default value if `'&'` is not in you list

    return ' '.join(lst[:index]), ' '.join(lst[index + 1:])

lst = ['John', 'Adams', 'Jr.', '&', 'George', 'Washington']

name_one, name_two = get_names(lst)

name_one # 'John Adams Jr.'
name_two # 'George Washington'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are going to combine the partial lists into strings, anyway, why not first join all the pieces and then split?

```
_list = ['John', 'Adams', 'Jr.', '&', 'George', 'Washington']
name_one, name_two = " ".join(_list).split(" & ")
print(name_one, name_two, sep=", ")
#John Adams Jr., George Washington
```

You can even process more than two parts using the same expression:

```
_list = ['John', 'Adams', '&', 'George', 'Washington', '&', 'Ben', 'Franklin']
name_one, name_two, *more_names = " ".join(_list).split(" & ")
print(name_one, name_two, more_names, sep=", ")
#John Adams, George Washington, ['Ben Franklin']
```

Comment: Thank you I went ahead and did it this way. Just curious, why did you put a _ before list "_list" instead of just calling it list?

Comment: `list` is the built-in list constructor and should not be used for any other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
l = [['John', 'Adams', '&', 'George', 'Washington'], ['John', 'Adams', 'Jr.', '&', 'George', 'Washington']]
for i in l:
  a, _, b  = [' '.join(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(i, key=lambda x:x=='&')]
  print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
('John Adams', 'George Washington')
('John Adams Jr.', 'George Washington')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method:

```
data22=['John', 'Adams', '&', 'George', 'Washington','john','&','paul','&','and','hi']

track=[0]+[j+1 for j,i in enumerate(data22) if i=='&']


for i in range(0,len(track)):

    if len(track[i:i+2])==2:
        real_data=data22[track[i:i+2][0]:track[i:i+2][1]]
        print(" ".join(real_data[:-1]))
    else:

        print(" ".join(data22[track[i:i+2][0]:]))
```

output:

```
John Adams
George Washington john
paul
and hi
```